# What do people do after doing a Ph.D. in ESL/TESOL/TEFL?

Tags: phd, language

A lot of universities are providing Ph.D. in English language teaching:
 1. [York University, UK](https://www.york.ac.uk/education/postgraduate/phd/phd-tesol/)
 2. [University of Cyprus, Cyprus](https://www.unic.ac.cy/tesol-phd-3-years/)
 3. [NYU, USA](https://steinhardt.nyu.edu/degree/phd-teaching-english-speakers-other-languages)
 4. [University of British Columbia, Canada](https://www.grad.ubc.ca/prospective-students/graduate-degree-programs/phd-teaching-english-second-language)
 5. ... ... ...

What do people do after doing a Ph.D. in ESL/TESOL/TEFL?

Does language teaching actually require Ph.D.?

Comment: Many people with PhDs do some mix of teaching their subject to bachelor's and master's degree students and research into their subject. Any particular  reason to think ESL PhD.s would be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Teach education students, most likely.

For those who complete a PhD and manage to find a position in academia afterwards, they'd most likely be teaching students who are studying in their general area. For someone who has a PhD in ESL education, they'd most likely be teaching education students, who are studying to become primary and secondary school teachers. They'd also likely continue their research in the area of education as well, investigating things like teaching methods or the use of technology in education.